# Is there a way to recalculate normals per animation frame?

Tags: animation, particles, normals, hair

Not even sure if this is the actually problem. This is my first model ever in blender.

I made a stuffed animal and wanted to do a 360 rotating animation kind of like a rotating display.

All the hair particles on the model look fantastic on frame 1, and then they all go to heck afterwards. If I advance the animation to frame 5 and render that one frame, all the hair looks terrible. If I recalculate normals on frame 5, and then render that single frame again, it looks great again. But any frame after will still look funky.

What setting am I missing to keep hair particles in place during the model rotation?

Thank you,

Comment: Could you include some screenshots of the mesh on frame 1 and 5? Afaik that shouldn't happen, is the camera the only thing animated?

Comment: Are you spinning the bear and have hair dynamics enabled? That would be physics bending the hair as it moves.

Comment: Yup hair dynamics was enabled, and in hindsight I should just be rotating the camera not the whole object, thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Yup hair dynamics was enabled, and in hindsight I should just be rotating the camera not the whole object, thanks guys